# How to call a SSL secured REST service within AWS Lambda

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

Is it possible to do an REST call to 
`https://owapi.net/api/v3/u/<Playername>-<BattleTagNumber>/stats` 
via the JAX RS REST client withi AWS Lambda and if so, what do I have to set up with the Java SSL? Currently I do the following:

```
  System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "all");
  SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
  System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1.2");//Java 8


  TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = { new InsecureTrustManager() };
  sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
  HostnameVerifier allHostsValid = new InsecureHostnameVerifier();

  client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().sslContext(sc).hostnameVerifier(allHostsValid).build();
```

But if I do so, I always get the following error:

```
javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: internal_error
```

With that javax.net.debug protocol:

```
trigger seeding of SecureRandom
done seeding SecureRandom
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
main, setSoTimeout(0) called
%% No cached client session
*** ClientHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1483983009 bytes = { 69, 214, 28, 204, 137, 202, 87, 217, 243, 178, 105, 174, 241, 76, 84, 41, 220, 36, 75, 185, 115, 175, 147, 24, 3, 43, 157, 220 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, sect163k1, sect163r2, secp192r1, secp224r1, sect233k1, sect233r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, secp384r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, secp521r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp160k1, secp160r1, secp160r2, sect163r1, secp192k1, sect193r1, sect193r2, secp224k1, sect239k1, secp256k1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
Extension signature_algorithms, signature_algorithms: SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA224withECDSA, SHA224withRSA, SHA1withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA, MD5withRSA
***
[write] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 207
0000: 01 00 00 CB 03 03 58 74   C9 A1 45 D6 1C CC 89 CA  ......Xt..E.....
0010: 57 D9 F3 B2 69 AE F1 4C   54 29 DC 24 4B B9 73 AF  W...i..LT).$K.s.
0020: 93 18 03 2B 9D DC 00 00   46 C0 23 C0 27 00 3C C0  ...+....F.#.'.<.
0030: 25 C0 29 00 67 00 40 C0   09 C0 13 00 2F C0 04 C0  %.).g.@...../...
0040: 0E 00 33 00 32 C0 2B C0   2F 00 9C C0 2D C0 31 00  ..3.2.+./...-.1.
0050: 9E 00 A2 C0 08 C0 12 00   0A C0 03 C0 0D 00 16 00  ................
0060: 13 C0 07 C0 11 00 05 C0   02 C0 0C 00 04 00 FF 01  ................
0070: 00 00 5C 00 0A 00 34 00   32 00 17 00 01 00 03 00  ..\...4.2.......
0080: 13 00 15 00 06 00 07 00   09 00 0A 00 18 00 0B 00  ................
0090: 0C 00 19 00 0D 00 0E 00   0F 00 10 00 11 00 02 00  ................
00A0: 12 00 04 00 05 00 14 00   08 00 16 00 0B 00 02 01  ................
00B0: 00 00 0D 00 1A 00 18 06   03 06 01 05 03 05 01 04  ................
00C0: 03 04 01 03 03 03 01 02   03 02 01 02 02 01 01     ...............
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 207
[Raw write]: length = 212
0000: 16 03 03 00 CF 01 00 00   CB 03 03 58 74 C9 A1 45  ...........Xt..E
0010: D6 1C CC 89 CA 57 D9 F3   B2 69 AE F1 4C 54 29 DC  .....W...i..LT).
0020: 24 4B B9 73 AF 93 18 03   2B 9D DC 00 00 46 C0 23  $K.s....+....F.#
0030: C0 27 00 3C C0 25 C0 29   00 67 00 40 C0 09 C0 13  .'.<.%.).g.@....
0040: 00 2F C0 04 C0 0E 00 33   00 32 C0 2B C0 2F 00 9C  ./.....3.2.+./..
0050: C0 2D C0 31 00 9E 00 A2   C0 08 C0 12 00 0A C0 03  .-.1............
0060: C0 0D 00 16 00 13 C0 07   C0 11 00 05 C0 02 C0 0C  ................
0070: 00 04 00 FF 01 00 00 5C   00 0A 00 34 00 32 00 17  .......\...4.2..
0080: 00 01 00 03 00 13 00 15   00 06 00 07 00 09 00 0A  ................
0090: 00 18 00 0B 00 0C 00 19   00 0D 00 0E 00 0F 00 10  ................
00A0: 00 11 00 02 00 12 00 04   00 05 00 14 00 08 00 16  ................
00B0: 00 0B 00 02 01 00 00 0D   00 1A 00 18 06 03 06 01  ................
00C0: 05 03 05 01 04 03 04 01   03 03 03 01 02 03 02 01  ................
00D0: 02 02 01 01                                        ....
[Raw read]: length = 5
0000: 15 03 03 00 02                                     .....
[Raw read]: length = 2
0000: 02 50                                              .P
main, READ: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
main, RECV TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, internal_error
main, called closeSocket()
main, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: internal_error
```

**EDIT 1:**
I got the following dependecies in the maven project - hoefully you now the HttpClient Version now...

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.connectors</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-apache-connector</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

**EDIT 2: Here is the whole log from AWS Lambda, if I execute the code in AWS Lambda.**

```
*** ClientHello, TLSv1.2    
Cipher Suites: [TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA]
Compression Methods: { 0 }
Extension signature_algorithms, signature_algorithms: SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA224withECDSA, SHA224withRSA, SHA1withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA
Extension server_name, server_name: [type=host_name (0), value=owapi.net]
Extension renegotiation_info, renegotiated_connection: <empty>
***
[write] MD5 and SHA1 hashes: len = 102
0000: 01 00 00 62 03 03 58 77 87 19 2B 1A 22 5B 19 D4 ...b..Xw..+."[..
0010: E3 22 6F B6 AE E9 C5 41 73 7A 24 0C 5A 63 E6 E2 ."o....Asz$.Zc..
0020: DA C5 81 1D 17 B7 00 00 06 00 9C 00 2F 00 35 01 ............/.5.
0030: 00 00 33 00 0D 00 18 00 16 06 03 06 01 05 03 05 ..3.............
0040: 01 04 03 04 01 03 03 03 01 02 03 02 01 02 02 00 ................
0050: 00 00 0E 00 0C 00 00 09 6F 77 61 70 69 2E 6E 65 ........owapi.ne
0060: 74 FF 01 00 01 00 t.....
AsyncHttpClient-2-1, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 102
[Raw write]: length = 107
0000: 16 03 03 00 66 01 00 00 62 03 03 58 77 87 19 2B ....f...b..Xw..+
0010: 1A 22 5B 19 D4 E3 22 6F B6 AE E9 C5 41 73 7A 24 ."[..."o....Asz$
0020: 0C 5A 63 E6 E2 DA C5 81 1D 17 B7 00 00 06 00 9C .Zc.............
0030: 00 2F 00 35 01 00 00 33 00 0D 00 18 00 16 06 03 ./.5...3........
0040: 06 01 05 03 05 01 04 03 04 01 03 03 03 01 02 03 ................
0050: 02 01 02 02 00 00 00 0E 00 0C 00 00 09 6F 77 61 .............owa
0060: 70 69 2E 6E 65 74 FF 01 00 01 00 pi.net.....
2017-01-12 13:39:37 <8b2d050a-d8cc-11e6-8262-5ddb1e7af2d2> DEBUG DefaultChannelPool:231 - Closed 0 connections out of 0 in 0 ms
2017-01-12 13:39:37 <8b2d050a-d8cc-11e6-8262-5ddb1e7af2d2> DEBUG Recycler:76 - -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacity.default: 32768
2017-01-12 13:39:37 <8b2d050a-d8cc-11e6-8262-5ddb1e7af2d2> DEBUG Recycler:76 - -Dio.netty.recycler.maxSharedCapacityFactor: 2
2017-01-12 13:39:37 <8b2d050a-d8cc-11e6-8262-5ddb1e7af2d2> DEBUG Recycler:76 - -Dio.netty.recycler.linkCapacity: 16
2017-01-12 13:39:37 <8b2d050a-d8cc-11e6-8262-5ddb1e7af2d2> DEBUG Recycler:76 - -Dio.netty.recycler.ratio: 8
[Raw read]: length = 5
0000: 15 03 03 00 02 .....
[Raw read]: length = 2
0000: 02 28 .(
AsyncHttpClient-2-1, READ: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
AsyncHttpClient-2-1, RECV TLSv1.2 ALERT: fatal, handshake_failure
AsyncHttpClient-2-1, fatal: engine already closed. Rethrowing javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
AsyncHttpClient-2-1, fatal: engine already closed. Rethrowing javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
AsyncHttpClient-2-1, called closeOutbound()
AsyncHttpClient-2-1, closeOutboundInternal()
AsyncHttpClient-2-1, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT: warning, description = close_notify
AsyncHttpClient-2-1, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
AsyncHttpClient-2-1, called closeInbound()
AsyncHttpClient-2-1, fatal: engine already closed. Rethrowing javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Inbound closed before receiving peer's close_notify: possible truncation attack?
AsyncHttpClient-2-1, called closeOutbound()
AsyncHttpClient-2-1, closeOutboundInternal()
[Raw write]: length = 7
0000: 15 03 03 00 02 01 00 .......
2017-01-12 13:39:37 <8b2d050a-d8cc-11e6-8262-5ddb1e7af2d2> DEBUG NettyConnectListener:148 - Trying to recover from failing to connect channel [id: 0x3351b9a8, L:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:32982 ! R:owapi.net/104.24.101.166:443] with a retry value of true 
2017-01-12 13:39:37 <8b2d050a-d8cc-11e6-8262-5ddb1e7af2d2> DEBUG NettyConnectListener:158 - Failed to recover from connect exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure with channel [id: 0x3351b9a8, L:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:32982 ! R:owapi.net/104.24.101.166:443]
2017-01-12 13:39:37 <8b2d050a-d8cc-11e6-8262-5ddb1e7af2d2> ERROR MasterOverwatchSpeechlet:186 - Fehler beim Lesen der Statistiken.
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.net.ConnectException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:357)
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1895)
at org.asynchttpclient.netty.NettyResponseFuture.get(NettyResponseFuture.java:160)
at de.mhproductions.ask.masteroverwatchskill.MasterOverwatchSpeechlet.getMasterOverwatchResponse(MasterOverwatchSpeechlet.java:158)
at de.mhproductions.ask.masteroverwatchskill.MasterOverwatchSpeechlet.onIntent(MasterOverwatchSpeechlet.java:70)
at com.amazon.speech.speechlet.SpeechletToSpeechletV2Adapter.onIntent(SpeechletToSpeechletV2Adapter.java:51)
at com.amazon.speech.speechlet.SpeechletRequestDispatcher.dispatchSpeechletCall(SpeechletRequestDispatcher.java:218)
at com.amazon.speech.speechlet.SpeechletRequestHandler.internalHandleSpeechletCall(SpeechletRequestHandler.java:152)
at com.amazon.speech.speechlet.SpeechletRequestHandler.handleSpeechletCall(SpeechletRequestHandler.java:115)
at com.amazon.speech.speechlet.lambda.SpeechletRequestStreamHandler.handleRequest(SpeechletRequestStreamHandler.java:89)
at lambdainternal.EventHandlerLoader$2.call(EventHandlerLoader.java:1139)
at lambdainternal.AWSLambda.startRuntime(AWSLambda.java:285)
at lambdainternal.AWSLambda.<clinit>(AWSLambda.java:57)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
at lambdainternal.LambdaRTEntry.main(LambdaRTEntry.java:94)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
at org.asynchttpclient.netty.channel.NettyConnectListener.onFailure(NettyConnectListener.java:162)
at org.asynchttpclient.netty.channel.NettyConnectListener$1.onFailure(NettyConnectListener.java:133)
at org.asynchttpclient.netty.SimpleFutureListener.operationComplete(SimpleFutureListener.java:26)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:514)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners0(DefaultPromise.java:507)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:486)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:427)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.tryFailure(DefaultPromise.java:129)
at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.notifyHandshakeFailure(SslHandler.java:1238)
at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.setHandshakeFailure(SslHandler.java:1233)
at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.setHandshakeFailure(SslHandler.java:1208)
at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1063)
at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:902)
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:411)
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:248)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:367)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:353)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:346)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1294)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:367)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:353)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:911)
at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:652)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:575)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:489)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:451)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:140)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1666)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1634)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.recvAlert(SSLEngineImpl.java:1800)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:1083)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readNetRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:907)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:781)
at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:624)
at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1097)
at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:968)
... 18 more
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.net.ConnectException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:357)
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1895)
at org.asynchttpclient.netty.NettyResponseFuture.get(NettyResponseFuture.java:160)
at de.mhproductions.ask.masteroverwatchskill.MasterOverwatchSpeechlet.getMasterOverwatchResponse(MasterOverwatchSpeechlet.java:158)
at de.mhproductions.ask.masteroverwatchskill.MasterOverwatchSpeechlet.onIntent(MasterOverwatchSpeechlet.java:70)
at com.amazon.speech.speechlet.SpeechletToSpeechletV2Adapter.onIntent(SpeechletToSpeechletV2Adapter.java:51)
at com.amazon.speech.speechlet.SpeechletRequestDispatcher.dispatchSpeechletCall(SpeechletRequestDispatcher.java:218)
at com.amazon.speech.speechlet.SpeechletRequestHandler.internalHandleSpeechletCall(SpeechletRequestHandler.java:152)
at com.amazon.speech.speechlet.SpeechletRequestHandler.handleSpeechletCall(SpeechletRequestHandler.java:115)
at com.amazon.speech.speechlet.lambda.SpeechletRequestStreamHandler.handleRequest(SpeechletRequestStreamHandler.java:89)
at lambdainternal.EventHandlerLoader$2.call(EventHandlerLoader.java:1139)
at lambdainternal.AWSLambda.startRuntime(AWSLambda.java:285)
at lambdainternal.AWSLambda.<clinit>(AWSLambda.java:57)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
at lambdainternal.LambdaRTEntry.main(LambdaRTEntry.java:94)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
at org.asynchttpclient.netty.channel.NettyConnectListener.onFailure(NettyConnectListener.java:162)
at org.asynchttpclient.netty.channel.NettyConnectListener$1.onFailure(NettyConnectListener.java:133)
at org.asynchttpclient.netty.SimpleFutureListener.operationComplete(SimpleFutureListener.java:26)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:514)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners0(DefaultPromise.java:507)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:486)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:427)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.tryFailure(DefaultPromise.java:129)
at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.notifyHandshakeFailure(SslHandler.java:1238)
at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.setHandshakeFailure(SslHandler.java:1233)
at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.setHandshakeFailure(SslHandler.java:1208)
at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1063)
at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:902)
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:411)
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:248)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:367)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:353)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:346)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1294)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:367)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:353)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:911)
at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:652)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:575)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:489)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:451)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:140)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1666)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1634)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.recvAlert(SSLEngineImpl.java:1800)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:1083)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readNetRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:907)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:781)
at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:624)
at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1097)
at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:968)
... 18 more
2017-01-12 13:39:37 <8b2d050a-d8cc-11e6-8262-5ddb1e7af2d2> DEBUG AsyncCompletionHandler:71 - Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
java.net.ConnectException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
at org.asynchttpclient.netty.channel.NettyConnectListener.onFailure(NettyConnectListener.java:162)
at org.asynchttpclient.netty.channel.NettyConnectListener$1.onFailure(NettyConnectListener.java:133)
at org.asynchttpclient.netty.SimpleFutureListener.operationComplete(SimpleFutureListener.java:26)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:514)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners0(DefaultPromise.java:507)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:486)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:427)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.tryFailure(DefaultPromise.java:129)
at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.notifyHandshakeFailure(SslHandler.java:1238)
at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.setHandshakeFailure(SslHandler.java:1233)
at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.setHandshakeFailure(SslHandler.java:1208)
at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1063)
at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:902)
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:411)
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:248)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:367)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:353)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:346)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1294)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:367)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:353)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:911)
at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:652)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:575)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:489)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:451)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:140)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1666)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1634)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.recvAlert(SSLEngineImpl.java:1800)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:1083)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readNetRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:907)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:781)
at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:624)
at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1097)
at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:968)
... 18 more
2017-01-12 13:39:38 <8b2d050a-d8cc-11e6-8262-5ddb1e7af2d2> DEBUG HttpHandler:157 - Unexpected I/O exception on channel [id: 0x3351b9a8, L:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:32982 ! R:owapi.net/104.24.101.166:443]
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:411)
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:248)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:367)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:353)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:346)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1294)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:367)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:353)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:911)
at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:652)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:575)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:489)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:451)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:140)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2017-01-12 13:39:38 <8b2d050a-d8cc-11e6-8262-5ddb1e7af2d2> DEBUG ChannelManager:370 - Closing Channel [id: 0x3351b9a8, L:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:32982 ! R:owapi.net/104.24.101.166:443] 
AsyncHttpClient-2-1, called closeOutbound()
AsyncHttpClient-2-1, closeOutboundInternal()
```

Comment: @DaveMaple See my adjustment in the question above

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue seems to come down to the [ECC cipher suite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_cryptography) and lack of support in this version of the openjdk. I was able to get it working by adding BouncyCastle to the project:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
        <version>1.56</version>
    </dependency>
```

And then adding the root, domain and SNI certs for owapi.net:

```
Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

// get cert
X509Certificate rootCert =
        (X509Certificate) CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509").generateCertificate(
                new BufferedInputStream(OwapiTestHandler.class.getResourceAsStream("/comodo-ecc-ca.crt"))
        );
X509Certificate domainCert =
        (X509Certificate) CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509").generateCertificate(
                new BufferedInputStream(OwapiTestHandler.class.getResourceAsStream("/comodo-ecc-domain-ca.crt"))
        );
X509Certificate sniCert =
        (X509Certificate) CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509").generateCertificate(
                new BufferedInputStream(OwapiTestHandler.class.getResourceAsStream("/sni235897.cloudflaressl.com.crt"))
        );

// add cert to keystore
KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12", BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME);
keystore.load(null, "".toCharArray());
keystore.setCertificateEntry("comodo-ecc-ca", rootCert);
keystore.setCertificateEntry("comodo-ecc-doman-ca", domainCert);
keystore.setCertificateEntry("cloudflair-sni", sniCert);
```

There's a fully working project on github here that includes all of the certs for owapi.net:

https://github.com/codeengine1/owapi-test
https://github.com/codeengine1/owapi-test/blob/master/src/main/java/com/codeengine/lambda/OwapiTestHandler.java

Comment: Hmmm...okay tried with only the AsyncHttpClient with no configuration in synchronous mode. Now I get the following exception javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure

Comment: It is set up to "No VPC".

Comment: You can use Kampfkeks-2498

Comment: You forgot an s for stats

Comment: I tried exactly the same thing, but in AWS Lambda I get the following exception: DEBUG HttpHandler:157 - Unexpected I/O exception on channel [id: 0xa1f0a1d8, L:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:39996 ! R:owapi.net/104.24.100.166:443]
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure

Comment: Yes, i am using 2.0.24

Comment: Thank you for your extensive help ;)

Comment: Sry for my inconvenience, but did you got any result so far?

Comment: I've "found" the problem. I used a Overwatch-API with a certificate, sigend by a authority and this is working, using a custom certificate leads to the problem. How can I set the certificate in my code, to use the one from owapi.net?

Comment: @MarcelHöll: finally got it working. See updated answer.

Comment: @DaveMarple Maybe you can tell me, what exatcly did you do to obtain the certs, truststore, ...?

Answer (score 0):

You most likely hit a JDK bug because you're running a version that isn't up-to-date. Upgrade to latest JDK8 (8112 atm).

Comment: Unfortunately aws would need to upgrade the openjdk for the Java lambda runtime

Comment: If you're a AWS customer, you're entitled to open an issue there and ask them to upgrade. If that's indeed a JDK issue that's been long fixed, it becomes an AWS issue then.

Comment: @StephaneLandelle Yes, AWS Lambda uses Open JDK java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.101-3.b13.24.amzn1.x86_64, if I try it locally, all works fine, If I switch to the AWS Lambda service, it crashes with the handshake failure.

Comment: AWS Lambda runs custom AWS OpenJDK builds. Only them can tell how they differ from public builds, like the one you have on your machine. Then, IMO: works on your machine + doesn't work on AWS Lambda = AWS issue, for them to investigate.

Answer (score 0):

First, test things locally, use java keytool to import ssl cert to cacerts. 
Then, add the cacert_new to same package of you java class:

```
String pathKeyStore = com.amazonaws.samples.SaveUrl.class.getResource("cacerts_new").getPath();
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", pathKeyStore);
```

package your code and deploy to aws lambda. should work the same way as local.